# How to set correct path to copy .apk to docker container

Tags: android, windows, docker, appium

How to set the correct path to copy `.apk` to docker container?

```
$ docker cp path/app.apk container-appium:/opt

docker@appium-test-machine:~$ docker cp C:Users/rnovakhatski/Desktop/BGPB-v5170003-01311723-prod.apk container-appium:/
opt
copying between containers is not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error `copying between containers is not supported` is because the `:` in the path `C:Users/rnovakhatski/Desktop/BGPB-v5170003-01311723-prod.apk` is making docker to think `C` as the name of container.

Try this

```
docker cp C:\Users\rnovakhatski\Desktop\BGPB-v5170003-01311723-prod.apk container-appium:/opt
```

OR

```
docker cp /C/Users/rnovakhatski/Desktop/BGPB-v5170003-01311723-prod.apk container-appium:/opt
```

One of this should work.

Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately I have similar errors: docker@appium-test-machine:~$ docker cp C:\Users\rnovakhatski\Desktop\BGPB-v5170003-01311723-prod.apk container-appium:
/opt
copying between containers is not supported
docker@appium-test-machine:~$ docker cp /C/Users/rnovakhatski/Desktop/BGPB-v5170003-01311723-prod.apk container-appium:
/opt
lstat /C: no such file or directory